# Add angle-brackets around link

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to insert < > on both sides of all links in a line.
The following is always true for my lines

- The links start with http://
- There are three words in a line
- a space separate the words
- each line start with two links and then a string or number

An line could look like this:

```
http://website1.com/123123  http://homepage.net/3846  INDONESIA
```

I have tried the following:

```
sed 's@^http:[^ ]+@<&>@g'
```

But I am doing something wrong :P

Can someone please post sed statement that does this?

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote this question.

Comment: Just to point out: detecting URLs is a hard problem to solve: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/

Comment: Hehe, that was my first approach, but I soon gave that up. Lucky for me then my URLs are always uniform and thus easy to recognize. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this one for virtuoso dumps:

```
sed -e "s@\(http://\S\+\)@\<\1\>@g" -e "s@\(^<[^>]*>  <[^>]*>  \)\([^<].*$\|<.\{0,7\}$\|<\([^h]\|h[^t]\|ht[^t]\|htt[^p]\|http[^:]\|http:[^/]\|http:/[^/]\).*$\)@\1\"\"\"\2\"\"\"@g" -e "s@\([^\.]\)[ \t]*\$@\1\.@g"
```

It is a bit bloated and you might be able to take out a few things, but it works for me.

Comment: That is funny because, I need to fix the output of a virtuoso SPARQL construct query.  I see you also add a dot at the end of the line end then add quotes for literals. I do not know if the last part is necessary in my dataset but I'll use it.

Answer (score 2):

this sed one-liner worked here:

```
sed 's@\bhttp://\S*@<&>@g'
```

test with your data:

```
kent$ sed 's@\bhttp://\S*@<&>@g'<<<"http://website1.com/123123  http://homepage.net/3846  INDONESIA"
<http://website1.com/123123>  <http://homepage.net/3846>  INDONESI
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake is that you assume that "http" is at the begining of the string (with the anchor `^`), but it is not always the case. The second error is that you use the `+` that must be escaped in basic mode, but you can use `*` instead:

```
sed 's@\(^\| \)\(http:[^ ]*\)@\1<\2>@g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/http:[^ ]+/<&>/g'
```

test:

```
$ echo "http://website1.com/123123  http://homepage.net/3846  INDONESIA" | sed -r 's/http:[^ ]+/<&>/g'
<http://website1.com/123123>  <http://homepage.net/3846>  INDONESIA
```